# Unable to use a Swift class from JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, xcode, swift, swift-playground, javascriptcore

I'm looking to instantiate a Swift Class in a JavaScriptCore context.

I tried different syntaxes with a Playground, also tried on Xcode 6.4 (Swift 1.2) and Xcode 7 beta 3 (Swift 2.0) but no success =-(

Maybe I'm missing something.

In the more complex example I found on the net, the protocol 'create' function was defined as a 'class func' but the compiler refuses this syntax telling "Class methods are only allowed within classes; use 'static' to declare a static method"... so I did.

Here is my code (OS X 10.10.4 - Xcode 6.4). I use a Playground :

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation
import JavaScriptCore

let context = JSContext()

// errors handling
context.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
    println("JS Error: \(exception)")
}

@objc
protocol PersonJavaScritMethod : JSExport {
    func sayHello()
    static func create(name : String) -> Person
}

class Person : NSObject, PersonJavaScritMethod {
    var name : String!

    init(name:String) {
        super.init()
        println("# init done #")
        self.name = name
    }

    class func create(name : String) -> Person {
        return Person(name: name)
    }

    func sayHello() {
        println("Hello \(name)")
    }
}

let aPerson = Person.create("Toto")
// -> ok : console output : "# init done #"
aPerson.sayHello()
// -> ok : console output : "Hello Toto"

context.globalObject.setObject(Person.self, forKeyedSubscript: "Person")
context.evaluateScript("Person.create('Mike')")
// -> not ok : console output :
// "JS Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Person.create('Mike')')"
```

Comment: I tried the same code in a command line application instead of a Playgroud and it works ==> maybe a Playground bug / limitation ?

Comment: It also works if I put the protocol and class declaration in a separate file in the Sources folder of the PlayGround, adding "public" before "class Person", "class func create" and "func sayHello", and delete "@objc (Person)"

Comment: Tnx, saved my time. As you mentioned it is only a playground bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is working with XCode 8.2.1 and swift3 (I bet this has to do with new method name/label management in Swift 3):

```
context.evaluateScript("Person.createWithName('Mike')")
```